# Writing Binary Data to Response in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to find a way to write a `byte[]` to the Response object inside some custom middleware. There is a `WriteAsync` extension method, that allows me to write a string, but need to write a byte array.

Googling this points me to the `BinaryWrite` method on the `Response` object but this is the one in `System.Web`, not `Microsoft.AspNet.Http`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [ASP.NET Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/822), you can write the `byte[]` in the `Response.Body`:

```
await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Is this what you were looking for?